# Using appenTab() function in Shiny and plotting ggplot

Tags: r, shiny

This is my code

I am using `appendTab()` function from `shiny` package.

I have ***2 Questions***:

---

***1)*** Why I have 2 plots displayed on the screen? It should give me only one

---

**2)** Regarding best practice, I am using `appendTab()` function the right way? The only way I could imagine using `appendTab()` function was inside de `observeEvent`. And also the `plotOutput()` and `output$[[ ... ]]` code are at the same time inside observeEvent(). Is it right?

Bellow is my code:

---

```
library(shiny)

colors_hex <- c("#FF0000", "#00FF00", "#0000FF", "#FFFF00", "#FF00FF")

data <- gapminder::gapminder %>% filter(country == 'Italy')
ui <- fluidPage(
  navbarPage(
    "Add Chart Panels",
    id = "tabs"
  ),
  actionButton("add_tab", "Add Panel"),tableOutput("head"),
  
  uiOutput("tabs_content")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  

observeEvent(input$add_tab, {
    tab_name <- paste("Regressão Modelo ", input$add_tab)
    appendTab(
      inputId = "tabs",
      tabPanel(tab_name,  
              
               plotOutput(paste0("plot",input$add_tab)),
               output[[paste0("plot",input$add_tab)]] <- renderPlot({
                 ggplot(data = data,aes(x = year, y = pop)) + geom_line( color = colors_hex[input$add_tab])
               })
               ),
      select = TRUE
    )
  })
 
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Try `output[[...]]` outside the observer.

Comment: @YBS thanks for your time. I have this error message: rror in input$add_tab : 
  Can't access reactive value 'add_tab' outside of reactive consumer.
ℹ Do you need to wrap inside reactive() or observe()?

Comment: I meant outside appendTab().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  plot_list <- list()
  observeEvent(input$add_tab, {
    tab_name <- paste("Regressão Modelo ", input$add_tab)
    appendTab(
      inputId = "tabs",
      tabPanel(tab_name,  
               
               plotOutput(paste0("plot",input$add_tab)),
               
      ),
      select = TRUE
    )
    n <- input$add_tab
    lapply(1:n, function(i){
      plot_list[[i]] <<- ggplot(data = data,aes(x = year, y = pop)) + geom_line( color = colors_hex[i])
      output[[paste0("plot",i)]] <- renderPlot({
        plot_list[[i]]
      })
    })
  })
  
}
```